# Why is the callback not being executed? - Smalltalk

Tags: select, callback, smalltalk, seaside

I am making a web application that adds YouTube videos to playlists. A select is displayed next to thumbnails of videos containing the user's current playlists, and when the user clicks the submit button, the current video should be added to the selected playlist. However, I am running into a problem where the callback does not seem to be executing. I apologize if the answer is trivial, because I cannot see where the problem is coming from:

```
html form with: 
    [html select with:
                     self session getPlaylists keysDo:
                     [:k | html option value: k; with: [html text:k]]];
                 callback: [:v | self session addVideo: ((searchRes at: 'items') 
                                 at: (i*2+x)) toPlaylist: v. Transcript show: 'call'].
    html break.
    html submitButton class:'tiny button';value: 'Add to Playlist']
```

Sorry, the code is a bet messy. Basically, the callback isn't executing (I know this because 'call' is not being printed to the transcript when the form is submitted). Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using seaside? Can you reproduce the problem with a simple form and select? Why don't you use `WASelectTag>>list:` to pass the objects and `WASelectTag>>label` to specify the label block for each element (much cleaner).

Answer (score 2):

Because the  `with:` block is in the wrong place. In Seaside, the `with:` is the last message in the cascade when using the html canvas.

In some more detail:

```
WATagBrush>>with: anObject
"Render anObject into the receiver. Make sure that you call #with: last in the cascade, as this method will serialize the tag onto the output document."

    self openTag.
    super with: [
        self before.
        canvas render: anObject.
        self after ].
    self isClosed
        ifFalse: [ self closeTag ]
```

where the super is a call to `WABrush>>with:`

```
WABrush>>with: 
    with: aBlock
    canvas nest: aBlock.
    closed := true
```

so the callback is never written in the response document that the server sends to your browser.